# VBA AutoFilter regional date format issue

Tags: vba, date, format, autofilter

I am trying to use `AutoFilter` to filter out results based on a date value that comes from a `DTPicker`.

For example, I pick Sept 1st from `DTPicker1` as below:

[image]

Then in the `VBA` code, I do this:

```
Worksheets("WS_Name").Range("A5:L5").AutoFilter _
 field:=3, _
 Criteria1:=">" & DTPicker1.Value, _
```

Then the filter strangely gets applied to Jan 9th instead of Sept 1st. So, using the format `DD/MM/YYYY`, it gets applied to `09/01/2013` instead of `01/09/2014`

I checked the calendar settings on the OS and they are setup correctly.

[image]

Also made sure that the `DTPicker1.Value` is formatted correctly by using `MsgBox DTPicker1.Value`

[image]

So why is the `AutoFilter` behaving like this? How can I force it to work in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the VBA [only understands American Date Format](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-dates.htm).

So try converting the Date value in the `DTPicker1` to the American Date format, like so.

```
Worksheets("WS_Name").Range("A5:L5").AutoFilter _
 field:=3, _
 Criteria1:=">" & Format(DTPicker1.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy"), _
```